# Printing files over USB drive (Ender 3 Pro)

Tags: creality-ender-3, usb

Is this possible? I know that the controller board of the printer is normally controlled (when using USB) by an active computer sending data, but I was wondering if it could be reversed so that the board retrieves files from a USB flash drive? My SD card keeps failing and is overall frustrating to work with, so USB would be a nice option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

There are two types of USB devices: host, such as a PC, and device, such as a thumb drive. (Actually, there is a third type, on-the-go, which can act as either.)

The Ender 3 mainboard is a USB device which means that it can only connect to a USB host. You cannot directly connect two USB devices, such as the Ender 3 and a thumb drive) and have them work.

One option would be to set up [OctoPrint software](https://octoprint.org/) on a [Raspberry PI](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) single-board computer and connect that by USB to the printer.

Comment: benefit of OctoPrint: you can start (and monitor) print jobs from the LAN